# what are the available components i can use in a Custom Theme Layout

Tags: lightning-community, lightning-community-template

I am trying to create a custom theme layout but the lack of proper documentation is a little frustrating.

The following is the only information I could find about supported Aura.Component[] names. But I am missing the notifications section.

```
<aura:attribute name="search" type="Aura.Component[]" required="false"/>
<aura:attribute name="profileMenu" type="Aura.Component[]" required="false"/>
<aura:attribute name="navBar" type="Aura.Component[]" required="false"/>
```

Is there any other documentation that I am not aware of, or a way to re-use that compactHeader that is used in the other salesforce Themes?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
I think the previous text was not very clear, what I am trying to do is to create a Theme layout using the Build your own theme, that has no navigation header.

I see that the other themes available are using this compactHeader but I cannot seem to be able to re-use, so I am trying to recreate it, I can work with the std component mentioned earlier but I am missing a key feature that is the notification section.

I am trying to find some documentation listing all the possible component names available (if exists) or a way of reusing the compactHeader.

Answer (score -1):

Found a solution to my issue using forceCommunity:notifications/

Comment: Please include some more details about how this solution works, e.g. include a code sample. See [answer] for how to produce a clearer answer.